# is it possible to load a HtmlPage from a string?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I have stored a webpage's HTML in the database.

I want to take advantage of HtmlUnit's ability to find/reference DOM elements.

Is it possible to load the HtmlPage object from a string (via a database column)?

Comment: just for interest: why are you persisting complete html-pages as strings inside the database? why not just store as simple file to filesystem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[StringWebResponse](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/StringWebResponse.html) may help.

Edit: example:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
    StringWebResponse response = new StringWebResponse("<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body></body></html>", url);
    HtmlPage page = HTMLParser.parseHtml(response, new TopLevelWindow("top", new WebClient()));
    System.out.println(page.getTitleText());
```

Comment: Problem is that TopLevelWindow constructor is protected

Comment: See <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136435/how-to-create-htmlunit-htmlpage-object-from-string> if you're using a recent version of HTMLUnit.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're using `HtmlParser.parseHtml` to create the `HtmlPage` object and just need a `WebResponse` to pass to it?

If so, [StringWebResponse](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/StringWebResponse.html) will wrap your string so you can pass it directly to `parseHtml`.

Comment: I can't find HtmlParser in HtmlUnit, are you referring to another lib?

Comment: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HTMLParser.html#parseHtml%28com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebResponse,%20com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindow%29

Comment: Problem is that TopLevelWindow constructor is protected

Answer (score 0):

uhhmm well yes.

You just need to serve it ( if you're using java you can use Tomcat for that ) and point your test to the served page.