# Javascript onload event not firing in HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit

I need to load a page from an HTML string, not from a server.

I use the method found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136435/how-to-create-htmlunit-htmlpage-object-from-string) :

```
String html = "<html><head><script>" +
              "alert('hey 1'); " +
              "function OnLoadEvent() { alert('hey 2'); }" + 
              "</script></head>" +
              "<body onload='OnLoadEvent()'></body></html>"

URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
StringWebResponse response = new StringWebResponse(html, url);
WebClient client = new WebClient()
client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
HtmlPage page = HTMLParser.parseHtml(response, client.getCurrentWindow());
```

I have also set an `AlertHandler` as follows:

```
client.setAlertHandler(new AlertHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handleAlert(Page arg0, String arg1) {
        System.out.println("ALERT: " + arg1);
    }
});
```

The example HTML above alerts "hey 1" only -- I would expect it to alert "hey 1" and "hey 2" -- this implies the body `onload` event is not firing.

Is there something extra I need to do to make the `onload` event fire?

Comment: ur problem is resolved ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was missing a call to `HtmlPage.initialize()`.

Comment: Thnsk for the answer, solution help me too